# Parsing macros found in user inputs

Tags: packages, xparse, package-writing

I am trying to parse macros that are found within user inputs for my custom draw package.

As an example suppose a user wants to set multiple quantities to have the same index. Currently I offer the possibility of typing the code line

```
\set {q1,q2,q3}=$*_{customSubscript}$
```

where `q1,q2,q3` are the quantities, which I have previously mentioned and * can be regarded as a placeholder for the quantities. Now, the individual parts of the input can be parsed using

```
\def\set #1=$*#2$
```

Let's say I want to offer my users the possibility to apply a macro like `\mathbf{}` to each quantity, hence the input would become:

```
\set {q1,q2,q3}=$\someMacro{*}_{customSubscript}$
```

Is there a way to parse the `\someMacro` and save it into a variable so I can apply it to `q1,q2,q3` later on in my code?

Desired ouput:

I would like to have a parsing function of the form:

`\def\set #1=$#2{*}#3$`

where #1 is `{q1,q2,q3}`, #2 is `\someMacro`, and #3 is `_{\customSubscript}`

Comment: Can you please show what output you’re expecting?

Comment: Hey Greg, I edited the question to give more clarity on the desired output

Comment: Sorry, but it's as obscure as before.

Comment: Could you maybe provide more in-sight on what you mean by output? I am not really sure what you mean

Comment: After processing `\set {q1,q2,q3}=$*_{customSubscript}$`, what should the printed result look like?

Comment: My package draws the corresponding pictures and q1,q2,q3 are labels found in the picture. So \someMacro would then be applied to the labels in the picture. If \someMacro happens to be \mathbf then the labels would become bold and they would all get the index "customSubscript". That is basically the idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113001/discussion-between-bakr-and-egreg).